# Java interfaces - parametric polymorphism

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

In Java what's the "correct" way to implement an interface where the parameters for a method need parametric polymorphism?

For example, my interface contains:

```
public int addItem(Object dto);
```

The interface is implemented by various classes but in each the dto parameter is one of various strongly typed objects such as planeDTO, trainDTO or automobileDTO.

For example, in my planeDAO class:

```
public int addItem(planeDTO dto) { ... }
```

Do I simply implement with the dto parameter as Object and then cast to the appropriate type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the DTOs all inhrerit from a common superclass or implement a common interface you can do:

```
// DTO is the common superclass/subclass
public interface Addable<E extends DTO> {

    public int addItem(E dto);

}
```

And your specific implementations can do:

```
public class PlaneImpl implements Addable<planeDTO> {
    public int addItem(planeDTO dto) { ... }
}
```

Or, you can simply define your interface to take in the interface/superclass:

```
// DTO is the common superclass/subclass
public interface Addable {

    public int addItem(DTO dto);

}
```

**Edit:**

What you may need to do is the following:

Create interface -

```
interface AddDto<E> {
    public int addItem(E dto);
}
```

And implement it in your DAOs.

```
class planeDAO implements AddDto<planeDTO> {
    public int addItem(planeDTO dto) { ... }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in common between the DTOs, hence I wanted to use Object in the interface, but I still want type checking in the implementation.

Comment: @Bob, if those objects have no common type, then in order to validate type I think you will need a different class for each dto type.  It would be very beneficial if you could give the dto's an interface and a few common methods.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'm not sure what you mean "different class for each dto type" unless you meant different interface for each dto and dao combination? Each DTO holds very different information and I'd like to stick with the DAOs for actual functionality so I don't intend to add any methods to the DTOs. I guess the bottom line is I haven't missed something obvious and what I want isn't possible unless I come at things from a wildly different angle?

Comment: @Bob, well in order to use polymorphism like you specify in your question, yes you need to come at this from a very different angle.  Polymorphism only works when you have a type hierarchy.  You will need something entirely different if you are going to stick with objects that don't follow a specific interface or inherit some common superclass.

Comment: Thanks again, I genuinely do appreciate the feedback. I've played with this quite a bit and even if my DTOs were to inherit from a superclass I still cannot type a parameter as the superclass in the interface and type the same parameter as a child of this superclass in each respective implementation, I thought it would work but it doesn't. And after all, that's what I'm doing anyway except the superclass of my DTOs is Object. I welcome any further thoughts you have.

Comment: @Bob, can you rework the code to do the work on your DAOs?  (Assuming your DAOs have a better inheritance hierarchy.)

Comment: I don't follow... I'm trying to do all the work in the DAOs, I want them to implement an interface that includes addItem(Object dto) but in each DAO implementation of the interface the dto is a different type, e.g. addItem(planeDTO dto).

Comment: @Bob, Ah, that makes sense.  Sorry.

Comment: I just had a lightbulb moment on generics because of this. Perfect and many thanks for your time.

Comment: @Bob, glad to help.  I'm a big fan of lighting light bulbs!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an interface which provides the functionality you need and not reference the concrete types?

```
public int addItem(ITransportationMode mode);
```

Where `planeDTO`, `trainDTO` and `automobileDTO` all implement `ITransportationMode`

Comment: Thanks Aaron. The DTOs don't have anything in common (I chose them as examples for simplicity only) so ITransportationMode would literally be empty and in the implementation I wouldn't have type checking (assuming I type as ITransportationMode in my implementation too).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reach for something like [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)? What is the behaviour which varies depending on the type of the argument?

Comment: I guess it's akin to double dispatch. The DTOs each have their own SQL inserts inside their respective DAO addItem implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use generic methods:

```
public interface Addable{
   public <T extends DTO> int addItem(T dto){}
}
```

You can read more about generic methods at : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html